# How to properly manage Android background task?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have read many other similar questions but none seem to address the specific issue I am dealing with. My app needs to synchronize data from a server to a local SQLite database. However this process cannot begin until after the user has logged in via a LogIn activity. One of the options on the login activity is to "Remember Me" which means if the user closes the app and relaunches it the app will "auto-login" using the saved credentials from the last successful login. If that fails then it takes them to the login activity. So with that explanation out of the way...The syncing of data needs to be done in a background thread and the app will continue to run while data is being updated in the background. So far I am just using an Async Task and launching the task like:

```
dataManager = new DataManager();
dataManager.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

Now here is where my problem comes in. The user has the ability to select a menu choice to "log out". If they select that then it takes them back to the Login activity. Where if they login again I may need to do the following:

First I must detect is there already an instance of the DataManager task running. If so and the user is different from previous logged in user then kill the previous version of the DataManager task and restart it.

If the user is the same do nothing if the previous version is running (or has even finished running), else launch it.

Also if the user simply closes the app and relaunches it without Android having killed the task then I somehow need to detect that and handle if I should create a new instance of the DataManager or not.

Also I may get a push notification from the server which informs the app to perform the same background task so I should be able to control stopping and restarting a task.

Lastly there will also be a "Refresh" menu option when the user wishes they can select that to run the background task (if its not already running).

Periodically as data has been updated to the local SQLite database I want to be able to perform a broadcast to notify the Activities that they can "refresh" the UI by setting up a Listener on the activities that would be affected.

In an effort to summarize the entire question....

How do you handle running, stopping, restarting and detecting the state of a single instance of a background tasks?

Comment: Have you looked into otto yet http://square.github.io/otto/ ?

Comment: I took a quick look at otto but couldn't see the relevance it had to my question.

Answer (score -1):

Content Provider, SyncAdapter, and AccountManager combined solve this for you. 
(I wrote this, but pulling from random person's repo because it was for a MOOC assignment, and my version isn't public, but... still my name in @author -_-)

[AccountAuthenticatorService](https://github.com/rosterloh/coursera-android/blob/master/iRemember/iRememberContentProvider/src/edu/vuum/mocca/provider/sync/AccountAuthenticatorService.java)

[LoginActivity](https://github.com/rosterloh/coursera-android/blob/master/iRemember/iRememberContentProvider/src/edu/vuum/mocca/provider/sync/LoginActivity.java)

[ContentProvider](https://github.com/rosterloh/coursera-android/blob/master/iRemember/iRememberContentProvider/src/edu/vuum/mocca/provider/MoocProvider.java)

[ContentProvider SyncAdapter](https://github.com/rosterloh/coursera-android/blob/master/iRemember/iRememberContentProvider/src/edu/vuum/mocca/provider/sync/SampleSyncAdapter.java)

My personal Opinion is that you should NEVER -not- have a Content Provider wrapping your SQLite DB, But this is certainly true if you are making use of the Internet at all to sync data. (Note that a "content provider" does NOT have to be shared publicly, as a lot of new android developers think.)

The SyncAdapter service/manager will allow you to easily schedule background syncs and/or on-demand syncs. The benefit of this is that your app does NOT have to run a service or thread all the time. You have the SyncManager handle launching your SyncAdapter Service when it is needed. This saves battery life of the user's device, and it helps to clearly delineate where in your project netcode, etc. should go.